# Image overlay on hover css issue

Tags: css

Trying to add an image overlay on hover but it returns the background under the image and the image stays on top how would I fix this

```
<div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell content_overlay">
                                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($img['image'], 'carousel-image', '', ['class' => 'img-responsive myImg', 'data-track-content' => '']); ?>
                                        </div>
```

```
.content_overlay{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #FFF;

    &:hover{
        display: block;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
        color: #1f8dd6;
        z-index: 999;
    }
}
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: When you hover you set the div to have z-index: 999 - but the image is within that div. We need to think about stacking contexts and how to make the overlay come forward without the img coming forward, at the moment they all do.

Comment: I just put the z-index as a way to test it even without it its not showing

Comment: Yes you are correct - it isn't showing whether or not you have the z-index because the whole lot is moving 'forward' on the z axis together. I have put up an answer which keeps your css but separates out the img and overlay and repositions them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks what is the problem with the overlay not overlaying the img.

The basic problem is that the img is within a div which is being used as the overlay, so when the overlay z-index is increased on hover the whole lot 'moves forward' on the z-access so their relative positions on that axis are not changed.

If we separate out the img from the overlay and make sure the overlay stacks over the img then the hover will work.

Here's a simple example, maintaining all the CSS given in the question but separating the overlay element from the containing element. Obviously in the real version the php takes the place of the img element here. img and overlay are given position absolute so they sit in the same place.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .content_overlay{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        color: #FFF;
        rbackground-color:transparent;
    }
    .content_overlay:hover{/* taken out the & and written as pure CSS rather than SCSS/SASS */
            display: block;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
            color: #1f8dd6;
            z-index: 999; /* kept this but not strictly necessary */
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div <div class="slider-inner pop parentSlider-cell" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;"> <!-- given style just for this demo -->
      <img src="" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:blue;position:absolute;"/> <!-- using a blue square img element just for this demo -->
      <div class="content_overlay"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Since I was using sass I thought it should have worked from the inside but I guess it was wrong thanks I removed it from the inside and it started working

Comment: No I think you are right. It's just that I wasn't using SASS (and SASS wasn't one of the tags in the question) so I separated it out for the test. Should be fine for you to go back to using the & again.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide an image with an overlay like so:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#image, #overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

#image {
  background-image: url('https://www.licg.nl/media/1287/duitse-dog740x433.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

#overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container:hover #overlay {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="image"></div>
  <div id="overlay">This image is now hidden</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is pretty nice but my problem was that the colour that you put on top of the image keeps going under but I don't have anything else written so I don't get why its doing underneath the image

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question properly, but if you want to hide/show an image on hover it would be something like so:

```html
<div class="content_overlay">
  hover to show image
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" />
</div>
```

```css
.content_overlay img {
  display: none;
}

.content_overlay:hover img {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm for some reason it makes the image disappear completely with just the opacity: 0 and it appears again on hover when its 1 but I just wanted some transparent overlay on top of the image but it keeps getting underneath it